# Snapping using translate

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, snapping

Im trying to translate a vertex in 3D space while it should snap to closest point if it finds one.
I have tried with all the snapping parameters listed in the API can’t seem to make it work anyone has any idea? I have also forced to snapping mode with these lines:

```
  bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.snap_elements = {'VERTEX'}
  bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.snap_target = 'ACTIVE'
  bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.use_snap = True
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try what was answered in this thread:

https://blenderartists.org/t/can-a-modal-operator-use-snapping/1175190

Comment: I actually have a costum snap with ray_cast and kdtree implemented in my own operator but the performance is too slow when dealing with really big meshes and scenes that's the main reason why im trying to use the blender's snapping, but thx for the info